# How to wrap external libraries loaded with RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs

I have set up an Angular application with requireJS. Before deploying, I bundle everything into one and unique file. Usually, external libraries doesn't have a requireJS 'define' wrapper.

For example, the Angular Parallax library is written like this:

```
# https://github.com/durated/angular-parallax/blob/master/angular-parallax.min.js
angular.module("duParallax",["duScroll","duParallax.directive"...
```

Here is my main.js:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/angular-dev',
  paths: {
    angular: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min',
    angularScroll: 'bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.min',
    angularParallax: 'bower_components/ng-parallax/angular-parallax.min'
  },
  shim: {
    'angular': { exports: 'angular' },
    'angularScroll': { deps: ['angular'] },
    'angularParallax': { deps: ['angular'] }
  }
});
```

I'm using grunt-contrib-requirejs to then bundle all the libraries (not CDN ones) to one and unique file. This is what I get after bundling everything:

```
angular.module("duParallax",["duScroll","duParallax.directive"...
define("angularParallax", ["angular"], function(){});
```

But what I expect is **the code to be wrapped** within the define:

```
define("angularParallax", ["angular"], function(){
  angular.module("duParallax",["duScroll","duParallax.directive"...
});
```

How can I achieve the latest without changing the library itself?

**Edit:**
According to this other stackoverflow question, this is how it should work. But I'm also using grunt-contrib-requirejs to bundle my code and that might be the problem.

[Shim from grunt-contrib-requirejs not wrapping library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521423/shim-from-grunt-contrib-requirejs-not-wrapping-library?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry for the 'priority', this is legacy that I will remove. Angular is loaded from a CDN as you can see, so it's not bundled within the rest of the libraries. It means that in my generated file, "angular" is not defined yet, that's why I expect it to be wrapped within "define" and then loaded when "angular" become available.

Comment: That bit you've added "I'm using grunt-contrib-requirejs to then bundle all the libraries" clarifies the issue quite a lot, so I'm retracting my comment. Yeah, it is not doing what it should do. Unfortunately, I'm not using this tool so I don't readily know what you'd have to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hope it will clarify for others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default r.js will not wrap non-AMD compliant libraries.
You need to add the following option to the grunt-requirejs-contrib settings:

```
wrapShim: true
```